# Irssi prevent logging joins/quits

Tags: irc, irssi

I use Irssi's autolog feature, but I'm tired of filling up my logs on relatively quiet channels with joins and quits. I've read the documentation for autologging, and I suspect that there is already a configuration that would prevent these from being logged. Unfortunately I do not see it in the documentation. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `autolog_level` setting.

According to the [documentation](http://irssi.org/documentation/settings#autolog_level_) the default is:

```
autolog_level = all -crap -clientcrap -ctcps
```

Try adding "-joins -parts" (and/or "-quits"?!) to it.

N.B.:  May have to force the log to reopen for new settings to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! Took a few months, but I still didn't have a solution :)